# Updating Dialog with content

Tags: android, file, search, dialog

I want to display a custom dialog while searching the files in SdCard. The custom dialog will display the files found one at a time. although this will be too quick to see all the files being displayed. I am not sure if it is possible.
 The approach i have thought so far is getting file list using Asynctask. but i couldn't update the dialog with the file names in real time. Has anybody tried this before.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update the Dialog two ways:

1. runOnUiThread()
2. onProgressUpdate()

but the thing is going to be same about Speed because you just want to update dialog with file name. So fetching file names from SDCard are going to be speedy task.